# How not to pass the format ( json, html, xml ) to the REST URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3 and I am using this new Rails 3 thing that it can do with respond_to and respond_with, so it my controller I have something like this:

http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/

```
respont_to :json

def show

    @organization = Organization.includes([:tableNamesBlah]).find(params[:id])

    respond_with(@organization)

  end
```

and I am passing it to a view with JBUILDER,....

so in the URL If I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/manager/1.json
```

it works fine and returns the data in JSON format but if I go to the same URI without specifying .json as the end of it then it won't return anything.

**How can I modify my code in a way that I can see the data but don't need to type .json at the end of the URL ?**

Is it something I should do in controller? or should I change the way JBUILDER is processing the data or is it something with the routes? 
Please let me know if you need to see other parts of the code

Comment: what was the reason for someone to down vote this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to set a default format, you can set it in your routes.rb file:

```
resources :things, defaults: { format: :json }
```

This should give you the behaviour you want (if I'm understanding your question correctly):

```
/things/1       # returns json
/things/1.json  # returns json
/things/1.html  # returns html
```

Comment: hmm theoretically I think you "answered" my question BUT not sure this is the BEST practice. As this is a REST SERVICE and there Should be a client that is calling this service, so we shouldn't need to specify the format. The CLIENT should tell it what it wants in the accept header request. Right?

Comment: @user1899082 Ahh, okay, didn't catch that part from the original question. From my understanding (and a quick google), Rails should take the accept header into account when determining what content to return. If you're getting something weird, is it worth double checking what accept headers you're sending in your request?